Why the async-code is printing these things and in this order?
I'm trying to understand asynchronous programming in Python, and I've stumbled to see the output of the code
import asyncio

async def my_coroutine():
    print("Coroutine started")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Coroutine finished")


async def main():
    print('a')
    asyncio.create_task(my_coroutine())
    print('b')

asyncio.run(main())

Output:
a
b
Coroutine started

Specifically, I don't understand why Coroutine started is getting printed in the place it is, and why it is getting printed at all.
I was expecting the output to be just
a
b


"why it is getting printed at all" because it is being printed. Why would it not be printed at all?

Whether Coroutine started comes before or after b (or isn't run at all before your script exits, if nothing keeps it running after main completes) is undefined; it could go either way, and neither is wrong. If you think something is unexpected or surprising, please be explicit in describing why it's a surprise.

You need to understand the async means that the process will run independently of other processes within the application. This means that any output they create may come in any order, depending on the way each process is started and run by the operating system.

Pretty sure Coroutine started is guaranteed to come after b (if at all). There's no other point at which the main task is capable of yielding the event loop, except when it ends (in this particular instance).

When you create a task, it is immediately sheduled in the event loop, and it starts executing as soon as possible (e.g first await syntax, or, for example, as in this case, completing the main() function, then the event loop has nothing to do, so it starts executing the next task)

Yeah! I understand that the task is getting scheduled and runs after completion of main() but why it isn't printing Coroutine finished? Why it is exiting preemptively?

By default when a new asyncio task is created with asyncio.create_task, ultimately if no task factory has been set (see asyncio.loop.set_task_factory), then the following code is executed:
task = tasks.Task(coro, loop=self, name=name, context=context)

If we look at the implementation of class tasks.Task we see:
class Task(futures._PyFuture):
    ...
    def __init__(self, coro, *, loop=None, name=None, context=None, eager_start=False):
        ...
        if eager_start and self._loop.is_running():
            self.__eager_start()
        else:
            self._loop.call_soon(self.__step, context=self._context)
            _register_task(self)

        ...

The eager_start argument was added in Python 3.12.2 and if True results in the task running immediately. Otherwise, asyncio.loop.call_soon in invoked to "Schedule the callback callback to be called with args arguments at the next iteration of the event loop."
In this case the callback is self.__step, which runs the coroutine associated with the task. When the coroutine that created the new task issues an await or returns, then callbacks that have been scheduled with call_soon will be executed in the order they were scheduled. For example:
import asyncio

def my_callback():
    print('my_callback')

async def my_coro():
    print('my_coro')

async def main():
    asyncio.get_running_loop().call_soon(my_callback)
    t = asyncio.create_task(my_coro())
    print('main returning')

asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
main returning
my_callback
my_coro

If you have Python 3.12.2, you can "eagerly start" the task by defining a custom task factory or by explicitly creating the asyncio.Task instance as follows:
import asyncio

def my_callback():
    print('my_callback')

async def my_coro():
    print('my_coro')

async def main():
    asyncio.get_running_loop().call_soon(my_callback)
    t = asyncio.Task(my_coro(), loop=asyncio.get_running_loop(), eager_start=True)
    print('main returning')

asyncio.run(main())

Now my_coro runs immediately when the new task is created and the output is:
my_coro
main returning
my_callback

Why Isn't Your Coroutine Completing?
The following code ...
import asyncio

async def my_coro():
    print('my_coro started')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('my_coro ended')

async def main():
    t = asyncio.create_task(my_coro())
    print('main returning')

asyncio.run(main())

... prints:
my_coro started
main returning

This is what is occurring:

The code asyncio.run(main()) create an event loop and runs coroutine main until it is "complete" (i.e. it returns).
Coroutine main() creates a new task in which a call to asyncio.loop.call_soon is made so that the next time main() either issues an await statement or returns the execution of my_coro will begin. As long as my_coro does not issue an await it will continue executing. But in this case it is issuing an await asyncio.sleep(1). As a result the return that main() initially made can now complete and we are back in the asyncio.run(main()) code. asyncio.run will now complete its execution by calling stop on the event loop it created to run main().
asyncio.run(main()) has now completed and since there are no more statements following this, the program terminates even though there is a task that had been created but never completed.

If were to remove the call to await asyncio.sleep(1) in my_coro, it would execute to the end before main() can completely return. The bottom line is that creating a task is no guarantee that it will run until completion. To ensure that, you must:

Make sure that there is always a reference to the task that has been created. In your code you execute asyncio.create_task(my_coroutine()) and do not even bother to save the Task instance reference that is returned. Once that reference is garbage collected, your task will be prematurely terminated.
Before a program exits (in your code that occurs implicitly after the statement asyncio.run(main()) has finished executing, an await must be issued for any task that you want to complete before exiting.

So your code could be modified as follows (just one possibility):
import asyncio

async def my_coroutine():
    print("Coroutine started")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Coroutine finished")

async def main():
    print('a')
    t = asyncio.create_task(my_coroutine())
    print('b')
    await t  # Wait for t to complete:

asyncio.run(main())

Here is another possibility:
import asyncio

tasks_to_await_at_termination = []

async def my_coroutine():
    print("Coroutine started")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Coroutine finished")

async def main():
    print('a')
    t = asyncio.create_task(my_coroutine())
    # The task will be awaited before we exit:
    tasks_to_await_at_termination.append(t)
    print('b')

async def main_runner():
    await main()
    # Await all tasks that have not been awaited:
    for task in tasks_to_await_at_termination:
        try:
            await task
        except Exception:
            pass

asyncio.run(main_runner())


Thanks for the detailed answer but I'm still not getting why my_coroutine() isn't executing completely. As your code and my experiments suggest, if I comment out the await asyncio.sleep(5) then the coroutine does execute to the last line.

I have updated my answer with Why Isn't Your Coroutine Completing?.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task

Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution. Return the Task object.

Even though you're not awaiting the task, it's still being scheduled by asyncio, which is why you see output. As some comments have noted, this behavior is not guaranteed, and the coroutine's print may happen before or after "b" is printed, or the program may end before it is printed.
When

I, now, understand that the task is being scheduled by asyncio, but why it is exiting preemptively (before printing Coroutine finished)?

Because you're not awaiting the completion of my_coroutine. When it gets to the asyncio.sleep() line, it's done executing (for the current task execution round), and because there's nothing the program is waiting for before exiting (main has already returned), it ends
